# python compare two dates

Tags: python, linux

i am subtracting two dates and computing the difference in hours

```
c_date = "2011-03-23 12:52:14"
c_obj_date = datetime.datetime.strptime(c_date, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
n_date = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
print "Creation Date:", c_date
print "Current Date: ", n_date
hours = abs(n_date - c_obj_date).total_seconds() / 3600.0
print hours
```

however this gives me this error:

```
  File "./eight.py", line 69, in zabbix_result
    hours = abs(n_date - c_obj_date).total_seconds() / 3600.0
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'datetime.datetime'
```

i am using python2.4

UPDATE:

i now used

```
n_date = datetime.datetime.now()
```

but the total_seconds() wont work in python2.4?? any idea how i can subtract two datetime object and get the hour difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

n_date is a string and c_obj_date is a datetime.datetime object.  I'm not sure where you're getting the .total_seconds() method from either (it's not a timedelta member...). Try something like this:

```
 c_date = "2011-03-23 12:52:14"
 c_obj_date = datetime.datetime.strptime(c_date, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
 n_date = datetime.datetime.now()

 print "Creation Date:", c_date
 print "Current Date: ", n_date

 absdiff = abs(n_date - c_obj_date)
 hours = (absdiff.days * 24 * 60 * 60 + absdiff.seconds) / 3600.0

 print hours
```

Comment: total_seconds was introduced in Python 2.7: http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#datetime.timedelta.total_seconds

Answer (score 2):

Look at the error message. The type on the left side of the operand is a `str`. The problem is in the third line. Try removing the `strftime` part.

Answer (score 1):

The type of `n_date` is a string. The type of `c_obj_date` is a datetime which means you can't subtract one from the other. That's also what the error message says.

You probably meant to do the following: `datetime.datetime.now() - c_obj_date`. You now have a [`timedelta`](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#timedelta-objects) and you can obtain the number of seconds using the method below.

The [`total_seconds()`](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#datetime.timedelta.total_seconds) method was introduced in Python 2.7 and you are using Python 2.4 so that won't work. If you wish to do it in Python 2.4, simply follow the method of computation in the docs:

```
(td.microseconds + (td.seconds + td.days * 24 * 3600) * 10**6) / 10**6
```

where `td` is equal to `datetime.datetime.now() - c_obj_date`.

Comment: I've added a way to compute the number of seconds to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You need to work with the datetime object.

Change this line:

```
n_date = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
```

with:

```
n_obj_date = datetime.datetime.now()
```

And adjust the following ones to:

```
print "Creation Date:", c_date
print "Current Date: ", n_obj_date.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
hours = abs(n_obj_date - c_obj_date).total_seconds() / 3600.0
print hours
```

This way you'll be doing a subtraction between two datetime objects.

Answer (score 1):

strftime converts a timey-object to a string, strptime parses a string to a timey object.

thus n_date is a string.